# Why it doesn't throw any exceptions when attempting to mock a singleton using either Mockito or PowerMock?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, singleton, mockito, powermock

I have a singleton class "Fake"

```
public class Fake{

private static Fake instance;

private Fake(){

}
public static Fake getInstance(){
    if(instance == null)
        instance = new Fake();
    return instance;
}

public String getTestString(String s){
    return s;
}
}
```

I want to create a mock Fake object so I can mock method calls to non-static method getTestString(String s). I have used both Mockito and PowerMock (Mockito extension) in the way that comes below.

```
//using Mockito
Fake fake = Mockito.mock(Fake.class);

//using PowerMock
Fake fake = mock(Fake.class);
```

In both cases, as the code is attempting to mock a singleton (with a private constructor) I expect an exception to occur, but it just normally works. I suspect that there is something wrong with it and maybe it is not working actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocking doesn't instantiate a class, it creates a proxy for it. Having a private constructor or a constructor with parameters doesn't make a difference.

The behavior you're seeing is normal and expected.

Answer (score 0):

By using mocking, it means you are not testing the class itself, but want to dictate the behavior of the class so that it performs in an arbitrary way you want.

The mock is only useful when you are trying to test some other class which has a dependency on the class being mocked.

In your case, if you want to test the class being a Singleton, you should test on an REAL instance rather than a mock of the class.

Moreover, your method:

```
public String getTestString(String s){
    return s;
}
```

always returns the String you passed in, this does not look right to me and not sure what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not ever creating an actual instance of Fake, only an instance of a proxy that fulfills Fake's interface, the mock is succeeding.

Separately, regardless of whether Fake's constructor is private, Mockito cannot stub or verify static methods. If your real goal is to override getInstance, [you'll need to do so with PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13#Mocking_Static_Method).

However, by adjusting your system-under-test, you can skip Powermock and test your method with Mockito directly:

```
public class YourSystemUnderTest {
  public int yourMethodUnderTest() {
    return yourMethodUnderTest(Fake.getInstance());
  }

  /** Visible for testing. */
  int yourMethodUnderTest(Fake fake) {
    // ...
  }
}

public class YourTest {
  @Test
  public void yourMethodShouldReturn42() {
    Fake fake = mock(Fake.class);
    YourSystemUnderTest systemUnderTest = new YourSystemUnderTest();
    assertEquals(42, systemUnderTest.yourMethodUnderTest(fake));
  }
}
```

It's even easier if YourSystemUnderTest takes a Fake instance in its constructor, because then you can set up the reference to the Fake instance once in a setUp() or @Before method.